# Error with Input shape in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras to build a CNN and I have the following code snippet:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
```

After running this, I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

[image]

The shape of dataset is :
[image]

Please help me with the situation!

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code in Stack Overflow - just post the error itself.

Answer (score 1):

Conv layers expect your input to be an image type. Hence you need to specify/reshape to include channel dimension.
In your case your number of channels is 1.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,1, )))
```

Then you need to reshape you input also accordingly.
It should be of the shape (batchsize, num_features, channels)

So assuming your X is a numpy array

```
trainX = X[:30730].reshape(-1, 50, 1)
```

Comment: I am getting a new error
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_5 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30730, 1, 1)

Comment: Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems with the code you posted:

1. **Inconsistent input shape**:
   The error says that the your model expects input with `dim=3` but you pass it `dim=2`. 
   This is true, since a `cov1d` layer expects to get a **3d** tensor (#samples, #steps, #features). Your training data has `shape=(30730,50)` so `#samples=30730`,`#steps=50` and `#features=1`. #samples is passed implicitly (it is determined during run time) so, fix those lines:

   ```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,)))
   ```

   to:

   ```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,1)))
   ```

   In addition, you should re-shape your training data accordingly by adding a dimention:

   ```
   trainX = X[:30730].reshape(-1, 50, 1)
   ```
2. **Inconsistent output shape**: Your model is trained with `loss=categorical_crossentropy`. Training with this kind of loss means that you should one-hot encode your trainY data. So if you have x classes, each sample in trainY need to be transformed to an array with `length=x`.**But,** in your case the model outputs a single output:
   `model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))` so you should use `loss=binary_crossentropy` for classification problem of `loss=mse', for example, for a regression problem.